# Loadable Kernel Module: Unknown symbol malloc_sizes (err 0)

Tags: android, android-ndk, malloc, kernel-module

I have developed a Loadable Kernel Module (LKM) for android.

I use `kzalloc`:

```
device = kzalloc(ndevices * sizeof (*device), GFP_KERNEL);
```

and it worked for a while, but after an update of my android (since 4.1 it's no more working), I got following error on `insmod`:

```
insmod module.ko
insmod: init_module 'module.ko' failed (No such file or directory)

DMESG says:
Unknown symbol malloc_sizes (err 0)
```

This has something to do with `inux/slab.h`, that's what I know.

I googled for days over days and I'm very frustrated not finding the solution to fix this problem and get the LKM working again.

Can maybe anyone help me out?

CONCLUSION:

The accepted answer is correct: Try to remove the slab.h and define the missing methods as "extern". Or in your kernel-source, use "make menuconfig" and change SLAB to SLUB (see first comment in answer for more details).

The remaining problems are handled in a new, more specific topic:

[Interchangeability of compiled LKMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241174/interchangeability-of-compiled-lkms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to tell us the kernel versions. But looking up linux kernel versions and memory allocators, it looks like the default mainline kernel switched from SLAB to SLUB.

> By default, Linux kernel used a SLAB Allocation system until version
>   2.6.23, when SLUB allocation became the default.

Unless you're writing a module or something that depends on SLAB (which is very highly unlikely), then you probably don't want to be including `linux/slab.h` headers.

Comment: I'm really happy about your resonse! I'm building for kernel-version 3.0+ (newer android-devices). I just read, that I have to re-make the kernel with SLUB enabled (http://www.armtvtech.com/armtvtechforum/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=604#p6149). Means this I just have to re-make the kernel-source, then my module and than it should work? I won't flash my device. Just removing the #include <linux/slab.h> results in "implicit declaration of function 'kzalloc'".

Comment: `results in "implicit declaration of function 'kzalloc'"` Just declare the prototype in your module headers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yesterday I just remake the kernel-source with SLUB instead of SLAB and the module didn't cry for malloc_sizes (but it resulted in a kernel-crash ^^). This evening, I will try your suggestion and define kzalloc/kzfree as external and remove the slab.h-include.

Comment: Hm, first I rebuild the kernel with SLUB instead SLUB -> kernel-panic AFTER `module_init()` (a debug-log at the last line before `return` 0 was printed). Again build kernel with SLAB, wrote `extern void *kzalloc(size_t, gfp_t);` and removed the slab.h-inclusion -> `Unknown symbol kzalloc (err 0)` on insmod. My target-device has kernel 3.0.39 (OMAP Galaxy Nexus) and I used common-kernel 3.0.8, this should work, shouln't it?

Comment: Are you specifically using kzalloc? I'm not sure I can really give much more advice without seeing your source.

Comment: I think you answered the question of this topic - many thanks therefore. I have to play with SLAB vs. SLUB in the kernel-options (make menuconfig, see my first comment here). I will edit my question above and add some notes.