# Interchangeability of compiled LKMs

Tags: android, linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling, kernel-module

Is it possible, to use a Loadable Kernel Module, compiled for `3.0.8+ mod_unload ARMv5` (my self-make'd kernel) in a kernel with version `3.0.31-gd5a18e0 SMP preempt mod_unload ARMv7` (android stock-kernel)?

The module itself contains nearly nothing, just

```
// Defining __KERNEL__ and MODULE allows us to access kernel-level code not usually available to userspace programs.
#undef __KERNEL__
#define __KERNEL__

#undef MODULE
#define MODULE

// Linux Kernel/LKM headers: module.h is needed by all modules and kernel.h is needed for KERN_INFO.
#include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>        // included for __init and __exit macros

MODULE_AUTHOR("martin");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    //printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world!\n");
    return 0;    // Non-zero return means that the module couldn't be loaded.
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
    //printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up module.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

I'm forcing the insmod but then the kernel-crashes:

> <1>[  328.025360] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at
>   virtual address 00000061 <1>[  328.025695] pgd = c1be8000 <1>[ 
>   328.025848] [00000061] *pgd=00000000 <0>[  328.026184] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT SMP <4>[  328.026519] Modules linked in:
>   airstream_interceptor(+)

I use

```
CROSS_COMPILE=/home/adminuser/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-
KDIR    ?= /home/adminuser/WORKING_DIRECTORY/android-3.0
ARCH=arm
```

for both building the kernel and now building module. But the system on it should be inserted uses it's own factory kernel.

I try to build a kernel modul which can be used on several android-phones (arm,armv5,armv7 and so on) but I want to use 1 for all (if this is possible in any way).

(edit)

CONCLUSION #1

1. it should not be possible to compile one version for all ARM-devices:

   `compile LKM for kernel 3.0.8 for ARMv5 and use it on a kernel 3.0.39 ARMv7`
2. it may (untested at the moment!) be possible, to compile on the lowest level (ARMv5) and use it in higher levels (ARMv6, ARMv7)

   `compile LKM for kernel 3.0.8 for ARMv5 and use it on a kernel 3.0.8 ARMv7`
3. it may be possible to interchange the kernel-versions (maybe if simple LKM)

   `compile LKM for kernel 3.0.8 for ARMv5 and use it on a kernel 3.0.39 ARMv5`

Open questions at the moment:

1.)

I tried (with common-kernel 3.0.8 and omap-kernel 3.0.39) to build for ARMv7 but the result is always a ARMv5-LKM.

I manually edited the .config, removed the ARMv5-line and added the ARMv7-line (which was nowhere in the .config):

```
#CONFIG_CPU_32v5=y # I added the #
CONFIG_CPU_V7=y # didn't exist 
CONFIG_CPU_32v7=y # didn't exist
```

but if I then re-run "make" on the kernel-source, the file get's automatically edited and my v7-config where removed.
Some months ago, I remember this was no problem, I just added the 2 lines and it worked.

Is this a thing of the kernel-source or the used toolchain?

2.)

What is the difference between e.g. the "omap-kernel" and the "common-kernel" in view of the LKM-building? Just an other kernel-version (e.g. common-kernel has now 3.0.53 and omap-kernel 3.0.39)? I think I can "ignore" the specific variants and use the common-kernel for LKM-compiling?

Many thanks to alkalinity, auselen & Marko at the moment - you're helping me out of the mud.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to use same version of kernel.

Comment: I have developed a LKM which I use in my android app. For just my phone it would be no problem, but I would like to distribute it to others. Therefore I need this LKM for several devices I can't control.

Comment: You can't do that if phones are not rooted right?

Comment: Yes,  sadly I have no other possibility at the moment. Poorly I cannot answer in the next hours because my cable provider has a broken fiberwire at the moment :/ :)

Comment: It would be much better to submit another question for your open questions. Btw they are really open and specific. Closure is good.

Comment: Today, I read about "FUSE" and "CUSE" and successfully checked if I have the /dev/fuse on my phone. Maybe this is an anchor, have to read the articles first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  The Linux kernel is [architecture-specific](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt), and ARMv5 modules are not compatible with ARMv7.  There are different header files needed, which will have different instruction sets, or register mappings, or any number of important variants.

In any event, the kernel versions are different in this case too, which means that the kernel API can vary, and therefore the kernel module will not work in all likelihood, even if the architecture were the same.

You'll have to cross-compile separate versions of your kernel module.  This isn't too difficult if you have access to the whole kernel tree.  The manufacturer should have released their kernel sources (as per the GPL).  If they have not, they owe you sources.

If you're interested in reading up on the specifics of loading kernel modules, IBM has a great "anatomy" series of articles.  Here's on on [loadable kernel modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lkm/).  Jump to the section on "module loading details" to understand why the kernel rejects insertion of your module in the absence of the force-load.

Comment: Puh, that's a hard blow for me. Didn't read that anywhere. Is it then right that I can at least use kernel 3.0.8 (android 4.0), build a SIMPLE LKM and compile it for ARMv5, ARMv7 and so on and it "should" work in any newer kernel-version (e.g. 3.0.39, which is Jelly Bean). Or do I really have to build every constellation (impossible for an android-app)? Do I have to re-make the kernel-source for every case with ARCH=armvxx or is this just needed for the `make ARCH=armvxx .. modules`?

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news!  It depends what you want to do.  If you aren't using anything "special", like an API that has changed between releases, then you're OK without changing your code.  If anything has changed, you'll have to make the multiple variants, but that part isn't so bad.  You'll have to put in a bunch of #ifdefs by including <include/linux/version.h> and wrapping LINUX_VERSION_CODE around the variant parts.

Comment: I'm thanking you very much therefore! I think I'm not using specials and I saw those variant in 2.6 modules. What's with common vs.omap etc. (processor?)?

Comment: ARMv7 should be able to run ARMv5 binaries.

Comment: That's what I thought. You see my full test code above :( some months ago I build a LKM with ARMv7 and this worked on my ARMv7 phone.

Comment: @auselen Binaries, yes, but not kernel modules.

Comment: @auselen this is unlikely to be the case.  There are a whole bunch of differences between ARM SoC platforms that could result in kernel data structures being differently laid out, and substantial difference in code compiled into the kernel.   There is also the matter of the SWP instruction that is deprecated in ARMv7, and may or not be fixed up in ARMv7 kernels.    If you did manage to fool the kernel to somehow load the module, the result will probably be rather crashy.

Comment: @Marko crashing would dependent on complexity of the binary in case of memory model differences. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module#Binary_compatibility, I still don't think v5 versus v7 is the big issue in this question.

Comment: @auselen Another really good reason why this will crash and burn is that one kernel is SMP and other not.  Lots of synchronisation code compiles away to nothing on a non-SMP build.

Comment: I accept alkalinity's answer though auselen's answer is certainly also correct. You all helped me to clear my thoughts. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the same binary driver with different versions of Linux.

> > Linux does not have a binary kernel interface, nor does it have a stable kernel interface. ([source](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/stable_api_nonsense.txt))

Comment: That should probably be that you cannot *assume* that you can.  Probably there are pairs of versions which are close enough that a particular *subset* of functionality *will* work if told to try anyway.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't know actually. Even same version can have different configuration leading to a different interface / layout.